# Directional Derivatives (2 var)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Compute the directional derivatives of the following functions along unit vectors at the indicated points in directions parallel to the given vector.

$f(x, y) = x^y$

$(x_0, y_0)$ = (e, e)

**d** = 3**i** + 4**j**

The formula for directional derivatives = gradient f(e,e) ⋅ **v**

I got the answer $3ee^{e-1}+4\ln \left(e\right)e^e$ which is incorrect. What is the correct way of doing this problem? I can show my steps if necessary.

MY STEPS:

1. find gradient f = $(yx^y-1 , ln(x)x^y)$
2. gradient f(e,e) = $(ee^{e-1},ln(e)e^e)$
3. **d** = 3**i** + 4**j**

$(ee^{e-1},ln(e)e^e)$ ⋅ (3,4) = $3ee^{e-1}+4\ln \left(e\right)e^e$

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: work added work added

Comment: Your calculation is correct. It simplifies to $7 e^e$

Comment: If you want directional derivatives with respect to unit vector of d =(3,4), just devide by its magnitude $|\vec{d}| = \sqrt{3^2+4^2} = 5$. So $∇f⋅d⃗ /|d⃗ |=7/5e^e$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have $$\nabla f=yx^{y-1}\vec{i}+\ln(x)x^y\vec{j}.$$ Since $\vec{d}=(3,4)$ then $$\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{d}}{\Vert \vec{d} \Vert}=\frac{(3,4)}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\left( \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}\right)$$ is a unit vector. Then $$Df_{\vec{u}}(\vec{d})=\nabla f(e,e) \cdot \vec{u}=(ee^{e-1},\ln(e)e^e)\cdot \left( \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5} \right)=(e^e,e^e)\cdot \left( \frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5}\right)=\frac{7}{5}e^e.$$

This is the directional derivative with respect to the unit vector $\vec{u}=\dfrac{\vec{d}}{\Vert \vec{d} \Vert}$.